# permission denied when mount in kubernetes pod with root user

Tags: kubernetes

When  I using this command in kubernetes v1.18 jenkins's master pod to mount a nfs file system:

```
root@jenkins-67fff76bb6-q77xf:/# mount -t nfs -o v4 192.168.31.2:/infrastructure/jenkins-share-workspaces /opt/jenkins
mount: permission denied
root@jenkins-67fff76bb6-q77xf:/#
```

why it shows permission denied althrough I am using root user? when I using this command in another machine(not in docker), it works fine, shows the server side works fine. this is my kubernetes jenkins master pod secure text config in yaml:

```
securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        fsGroup: 0
```

today I tried another kubernetes pod and mount nfs file system and throw the same error. It seems mount NFS from host works fine, and mount from kubernetes pod have a perssion problem. Why would this happen? the NFS is works fine by PVC binding PV in this kubernetes pod, why it mount from docker failed? I am confusing.

Comment: It might be better to set that up as a Kubernetes volume.  If the pod restarts or gets moved to another node, you'll lose any changes you manually make in that shell.  Generally container processes aren't allowed to do administrative tasks like mount(8), even if they're running as root.

Comment: so what should I do, I am now want to share folder in kubernetes jenkins slave nodes. and I want to using nfs mount to archive this, but when I config nfs volume, the kuberntes jenkins slave restart again and again. I tried to config kubernetes slave pods using pvc or  nfs but all failed today.@DavidMaze

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to mount nfs volume to a pod

First (directly in pod spec):

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pod-using-nfs
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: nfs-volume
      nfs: 
        server: 192.168.31.2
        path: /infrastructure/jenkins-share-workspaces
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: example
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nfs-volume
          mountPath: /var/nfs
```

Second (creating persistens nfs volume and volume claim):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 192.168.31.2
    path: "/infrastructure/jenkins-share-workspaces"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Mi
  volumeName: nfs

---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pod-using-nfs
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: example
      volumeMounts:
        - name: nfs
          mountPath: /opt/jenkins
  volumes:
    - name: nfs
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: nfs
```

EDIT:

The solution above is prefered one, but if you reallly need to use mount in container you need to add capabilities to the pod:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - securityContext:
      capabilities:
        add: ["SYS_ADMIN"]
```

Comment: I think you probaboly disunderstand my question point, your answer is right but did not answer my question.@HelloWorld

Comment: I add the config to pod yaml but it moved by kubernetes automaticlly and I do not know why would this happen@HelloWorld

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
securityContext:
  privileged: true
```

This needs if you are using dind for jenkins

Comment: I did not know why but I add this config failed.It seems the kubernetes auto remove this `privileged: true` key-value config.@Dashrath Mundkar